# Extracting images from multiple PDF files using hexapdf - hexapdf no such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm in my master thesis and I have to extract images from about 500 pdf files, some people recommended hexapdf to me for this. I was able to install Ruby and hexapdf and now I'm kinda stuck getting the images out of the pdf's since I don't have a coding background. Any tips?
Thanks in advance.

I tried using the basic command for only one pdf to see what happened by using 'hexapdf images' followed by the pdf name but the result was 'no such file or directory @ rb_sysopen'.

Comment: @KJ So HexaPDF the main library actually just needs a Ruby interpreter, no other dependencies are needed. If one was to use the accompanying CLI tool, one other library by the same author is needed. And for more complex document generation yet another. So at most two dependencies.

Comment: @KJ Ah, thanks for explaining your point! Yeah, I would also prefer having a single executable file when possible which is currently not really possible with Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `no such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`, then that signals that the file you are trying to open does not exist. It sounds like this is probably the PDF that you are trying to extract images from.

I would check that you are following help provided by [hexapdf documentation](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/documentation/tutorials/modifying-a-pdf-document.html#opening-an-existing-document) and that the path to your PDF is correct. If the file with your code and the PDF are in the same directory and you are running your code from that file, then you would do something like:

```rb
require 'hexapdf'

doc = HexaPDF::Document.open('my_pdf_document_filename.pdf')
```

If the file is somewhere else on the machine, it may be easiest to use a full file path instead of a relative file path which will depend on your system and such (e.g. `/Users/username/thesis/image_processing/files/my_pdf_document_filename.pdf`).